# show full string from string with \0 chars

Tags: c++, std

```
char data_[4096];
...
socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, 4096),
    boost::bind(&client::handle_read_header, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

when function `handle_read_header` is fired, `data_` contains many `\0` symbols in text.
with help of which way is it easier to view full (with stripped or escaped `\0`) string by `std::cout`? (by default \0 make end of string and don't show other)

Comment: The question is where your string ends? Or you may want to show all of 4096 chars?

Comment: @M.Elmi where string end, i know by bytes_transferred. i want out it by std::cout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seth kindly pointed out your requirement to make it "easier to view".  For that:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; ++i)
    if (buffer[i] == '\\')
        std::cout << "\\\\";
    else if (isprint(buffer[i]))
        std::cout << buffer[i];
    else
        std::cout << '\\' << std::fill(0) << std::setw(3) << buffer[i];
```

The above uses 3-digit back-slash escaped octal notation to represent non-printable characters.  You can change the representation easily enough.

(For a simple binary write, you can call `std::cout.write(buffer, num_bytes)` to do a binary block write, rather than `std::cout << buffer` which relies on the ASCIIZ convention for character arrays/pointers.  Then you could pipe the result into `less`, `cat -vt` or whatever your OS provides that helps view binary data including NULs.)

Comment: This doesn't show `NULL` characters in the output though, which may be misleading.

Comment: @Seth : Even worse, the behavior of writing a NUL character to `std::cout` or `std::cerr` is implementation-defined – some implementations segfault.

Comment: @ildjarn: interesting - which systems have you heard of segfaulting?

Comment: This is good advice that accounts for non-null, non-printable characters.  +1

Comment: @Tony : I don't remember offhand, but I've seen it crop up a handful of times in questions here on SO. In any case, implementation-defined behavior is always worth avoiding, and your edit does exactly that. :-]

Answer (score 4):

```
std::transform( data_, data_+size, std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout)
              , [](char c) { c == 0 ? '*':c; });
```

You can pick anything besides '*' of course.  If you can't use the current C++ facilities then just make a function that does what the above lambda does.

Comment: `missing template arguments before ‘(’ token` for `std::ostream_iterator(`

Comment: @askovpen: that's `std::ostream_iterator<char>`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, hmm `lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x`

Comment: @askovpen: well, this answer uses lambdas, which, as the compiler says, are available only in C++0x (now C++11). Pass the `-std=c++0x` flag on the compiler command-line to enable C++0x features.

Comment: It's not hard to rewrite in terms of an explicit function, where 0x features are unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's three options for stripping out the characters (as you asked), depending on whether you need to keep `data_` intact or not, or if you simply want a quick and easy way to stream out the characters.  Also, the last option shows an easy way to substitute a different (single) character for the null characters.  If you have C++11 support, all of these can be implemented as lambdas making the code much more concise.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   char c[] = "Ch\0ad\0's Answ\0\0\0er.";
   std::string data(c, c+19);

   std::string c1;

   struct is_null
   {
      bool operator()(const char c) const
      {
         return c == '\0';
      }
   };

   // if you need to keep data_ intact (copy)
   std::remove_copy_if(
      data.begin(),
      data.end(),
      std::back_inserter(c1),
      is_null());

   std::cout << c1 << "\n";

   // if you don't need to keep data intact, remove inline
   std::string::iterator nend = std::remove_if(
      data.begin(),
      data.end(),
      is_null());

   data.erase(nend, data.end());

   std::cout << data << "\n";

   // simplest approach, just stream out each byte and skip the null characters
   for(int x = 0; x < 19; ++x)
   {
      if(c[x] != '\0')
         cout << c[x];
   }

   cout << "\n";

   // If you want to decorate the null characters instead
   std::string data2(c, c+19);

   std::replace_if(
      data2.begin(),
      data2.end(),
      is_null(),
      '#'); // <--- this is the character that will replace the nulls

   cout << data2 << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can output the data "raw" (without replacing the \0) on a terminal by using `cout.write` and specifying how long is the string to write (it should be known in the read handler).

Otherwise, you can create an escaped copy of your data in a separated buffer, like this:

```
char data_[4096];
char escaped[sizeof(data_)*2];
size_t dataLength=...;
char *readPtr=data_, *writePtr=escaped;
for( ; readPtr<data_+dataLength; readPtr++, writePtr++)
{
    switch(*readPtr)
    {
        case 0:
            *writePtr='\\';
            *++writePtr='0';
            break;
        case '\\':
            *writePtr='\\';
            *++writePtr='\\';
            break;
        default:
            *writePtr=*readPtr;
    }
}
```

or replace it "on the fly" while writing (but it's probably slower).

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but I do think the `transform` idion is much more expressive.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I too like the `transform` solution, but I have always some fear for performance when outputting data one character at time, I've been bitten several times by slow, single-char `fputc` (although, with iostreams the problem should be mitigated by aggressive inlining). `transform` would be possible also directly on the buffer, but only when replacing a single char with another single char - which I think is suboptimal here (I'd prefer escaping, not replacing a NUL with a `*`); hence the classic C-style "`readPtr`/`writePtr` idiom".

Comment: -1 for C-style answer - we are in C++ land, why should we use C way of doing this, when there are C++ ways? And I don't say that `transform` is perfect here - there are many C++ ways to do it in nicer way.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: All true, perhaps, but I suspect the underlying reason why OP is trying to `cout` a (presumably) wire buffer is because he is writing debugging code.  In that case, to hell with performance, I say.

Comment: @Griwes:  The code posted by Matteo is legal C++.  I think I get what you're trying to say (basically the same thing I said), but the whole "C-way/C++-way" argument I find vacuous. Not every hole is round.  Even in C++ sometimes the best way to do something is to use techniques popularized in C.

Comment: @JohnDibling, the problem is not usage of C techniques - but misuse of it. There are cases when using C-way of doing things is completely sane, but in situations, when C++-way is not insane and can improve readability - I would always prefer C++-way. Also, OP seems to be kind of a novice in C++ programming; the greatest sin of most of programming "teachers" is learning to use C-ways even when there are C++-ways of doing things. And, again: what I'm saying is not "put C aside", but more like "use smart pointers instead of C pointers where possible" applied also to other aspects of the language.

Comment: @Griwes:  I agree with that -- much more than the sentiment to discard one approach simply because there is some C++-specific mechanism available.  In order to be a valid conclusion, there must be a better reason than simply "It's not the C++ way."

Comment: @JohnDibling, other reason? Ok, I already mentioned it - readability of this example is... well, low.